OpenVSwitch with nmcli
I am creating teamed interface with VLANs in OVS in fresh Fedora Server 40. Using ovs-vsctl without NetworkManager it always works fine, but now I am trying to create the same with nmcli.
nmcli connection add type ovs-bridge connection.interface-name sw0
nmcli connection add type team connection.interface-name team0 con-name team0
nmcli connection add type ethernet con-name team0-eno1 ifname eno1 master team0
nmcli connection add type ethernet con-name team0-eno2 ifname eno2 master team0
nmcli connection modify team0 team.runner lacp
nmcli connection modify team0 team.runner-active no

At this point ovs-vsctl show show empty config, and teamdctl team0 state show team interface is running well. Also tcpdump on team0 shows lot of traffic coming.
nmcli connection add type ovs-port connection.interface team0 master sw0
nmcli connection modify ovs-slave-team0 ovs-port.vlan-mode native-untagged
nmcli connection modify ovs-slave-team0 ovs-port.tag 22
nmcli connection add type ovs-port connection.interface-name port0 master sw0 
nmcli connection add type ovs-interface slave-type ovs-port connection.interface-name sw0 master port0 ipv4.method auto
nmcli connection modify ovs-slave-port0 ovs-port.tag 22

Now ovs-vsctl shows only internal port on the switch. tcpdump on sw0 shows no traffic at all. It seems switch does not have team0 attached at all.
dcc7a55b-ad9c-427b-a2eb-bda7e8a913d0
Bridge sw0
    Port port0
        Interface sw0
            type: internal
ovs_version: "3.3.0"

My questions are:

Is it possible to build all same kinds of network configurations with nmcli-ovs like one did with bare OVS?

Should ovs-vsctl always show the real state of a switch if it has been configured via nmcli?

I do not fully understand how nmcli work with add ovs-port. How it decide what I wanted: create port for future connection or I add existing connection to a port. Is there any problem in my commands adding ovs-port for team0 into switch?


